# Android, remove margin and padding from element

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

i've an activity that contains a LinearLayout (horizontal), i want that all elements inside the LinearLyout are attached, without margin or padding. I've tried many methods but to no avail.

This is my last attempt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.50" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:includeFontPadding="false" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/descriptionCounter"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/text_description"
            android:textColor="#33b5e5"
            android:textSize="60sp"
            android:includeFontPadding="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textActionCounter"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/text_counter"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#33b5e5"
            android:textSize="140sp"
            android:includeFontPadding="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/previousCounter"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/text_counter"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#33b5e5"
            android:textSize="60sp"
            android:includeFontPadding="false" />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

How can i resolve my problem?

Thanks!

Comment: i think you will have to create custom styles then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use android:layout_weight property in LinearLayout,this will override all th padding,

```
    <LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:weightSum="3">

 <TextView
    .
    .
    .
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<TextView
    .
    .
    .
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<TextView
    .
    .
    .
    android:layout_weight="1" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Always use RelativeLayouts. Not use Linear inside relative. The best practices in android:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html

Use for example commands like:

```
layout_above
layout_toRightOf
layout_alignParentTop
etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

In values/dimens.xml file you can set margins.

```
<!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">0dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">0dp</dimen>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look in your **RelativeLayout parent container** and instead of:

```
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

put **dimension to 0dp**:

```
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
```